# Powershell nested functions and parameters problem

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to have two main functions that you can pass other functions to. For example

./script.ps1 -local test1,test2

Here is my code, and -local works and also asks for another input after, but it doesn't actually output test1.

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='default')]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='default', Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$Default,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='external', Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$External,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='local', Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$Local
)

function RunLocal {
    switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        'Test1'  { Test1 }
        'Test2' { Test2 }
        }
        function Test1 {Write-Host "Test1"}
        function Test2 {Write-Host "Test2"}
    }
function RunExternal {}
function RunDefault {}

switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
    'local'    { RunLocal }
    'external' { RunExternal }
    'default'  { RunDefault }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish, but i think this might get you going:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='default')]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='default', Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$Default,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='external', Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$External,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='local', Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [switch]$Local,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='local', Position=1, Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateSet ('Test1','Test2')]
    [string]$ExecuteLocal = 'Test1'
)

function RunLocal {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateSet ('Test1','Test2')]
        [string]$Execute = 'Test1'
    )

    function Test1 {Write-Host 'Running Local -> Test1'}
    function Test2 {Write-Host 'Running Local -> Test2'}

    switch ($Execute) {
        'Test1'  { Test1 }
        'Test2'  { Test2 }
    }
}

function RunExternal {Write-Host 'Running External'}
function RunDefault  {Write-Host 'Running Default'}

switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
    'local'    { RunLocal -Execute $ExecuteLocal }
    'external' { RunExternal }
    'default'  { RunDefault }
}
```

As you can see I have added `ValidateSet` to the Local function so you can use this as a parameter stating either `Test1` or `Test2`.

Also, in function `RunLocal` I have placed the internal functions above the switch, because in Powershell functions need to be defined before they can be called upon.

Run it with `./script.ps1 -Local -ExecuteLocal Test1`

Hope this helps